# How to improve the speed of the calculation of this numerical-integration?

Tags: numerical-integration

The integrand includes k, Sin[2theta], and T. k is constant, theta is one of the variables (the other variables are x, y and fi), and T is functions of x, y, theta and fi. I found that it needs more than 2600s to work out the integration G = NIntegrate[k^2 * Sin[2 * theta] * T, {x, x0 - 5 * 10^(-10), x0 + 5 * 10^(-10)}, {y, y0 - 5 * 10^(-10), y0 + 5 * 10^(-10)}, {theta, 0, Pi/2}, {fi, 0, 2Pi}] (x0 and y0 have been given). How to improve the speed of the calculation? Many thanks!

The codes are as following:

```
Clear["`*"]
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
mu = 5;
HBAR = 1.05457266*10^(-34);
ME = 9.1093897*10^(-31);
ELEC = 1.60217733*10^(-19);
kc = Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2];
k = kc*Sqrt[mu];
afa = Pi/90;
d = 0.335*10^(-9);
v1 = kc^2*3;
v2 = kc^2*2;
v3 = kc^2*1;
K = 2.95*10^(10);

Kh[0] = {0, 0, 0};
Ks[0] = {0, 0, 0};
Kh[1] = {K, 0, 0};
Ks[1] = {K*Cos[afa], K*Sin[afa], 0};
Kh[2] = {K/2, K*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[2] = {K*Cos[afa + Pi/3], K*Sin[afa + Pi/3], 0};
Kh[3] = {-K/2, K*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[3] = {K*Cos[afa + 2*Pi/3], K*Sin[afa + 2*Pi/3], 0};
Kh[4] = {-K, 0, 0};
Ks[4] = {K*Cos[afa + Pi], K*Sin[afa + Pi], 0};
Kh[5] = {-K/2, -K*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[5] = {K*Cos[afa + 4*Pi/3], K*Sin[afa + 4*Pi/3], 0};
Kh[6] = {K/2, -K*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[6] = {K*Cos[afa + 5*Pi/3], K*Sin[afa + 5*Pi/3], 0};
integrand[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, theta_?NumericQ, fi_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{ks, r, p, M1, M2, S1, S2, S, T, S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, 
    S16, S17, S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, S26, S27, S31, S32, S33, S34, 
    S35, S36, S37, S41, S42, S43, S44, S45, S46, S47, S51, S52, S53, 
    S54, S55, S56, S57, S61, S62, S63, S64, S65, S66, S67, S71, S72, 
    S73, S74, S75, S76, S77},
   ks = {k*Sin[theta]*Cos[fi], k*Sin[theta]*Sin[fi], k*Cos[theta]};
   p[i_] := k^2 - Total[(ks + Kh[i])^2];
   r = {x, y, 0};
   M1 = {{0, v1, v1, v1, v1, v1, v1}, {v1, p[1], v1, v2, v3, v2, 
      v1}, {v1, v1, p[2], v1, v2, v3, v2}, {v1, v2, v1, p[3], v1, v2, 
      v3}, {v1, v3, v2, v1, p[4], v1, v2}, {v1, v2, v3, v2, v1, p[5], 
      v1}, {v1, v1, v2, v3, v2, v1, p[6]}};
   M2 := {{0, v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[1] - Kh[0] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[2] - Kh[0] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[3] - Kh[0] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[4] - Kh[0] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[5] - Kh[0] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0] - Ks[6] - Kh[0] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[0] - Kh[1] + Kh[0])*r]], p[1], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[2] - Kh[1] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[3] - Kh[1] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[4] - Kh[1] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[5] - Kh[1] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1] - Ks[6] - Kh[1] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[0] - Kh[2] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[1] - Kh[2] + Kh[1])*r]], p[2], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[3] - Kh[2] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[4] - Kh[2] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[5] - Kh[2] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2] - Ks[6] - Kh[2] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[0] - Kh[3] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[1] - Kh[3] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[2] - Kh[3] + Kh[2])*r]], p[3], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[4] - Kh[3] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[5] - Kh[3] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[6] - Kh[3] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[0] - Kh[4] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[1] - Kh[4] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[2] - Kh[4] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[3] - Kh[4] + Kh[3])*r]], p[4], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[5] - Kh[4] + Kh[5])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4] - Ks[6] - Kh[4] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[0] - Kh[5] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[1] - Kh[5] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[2] - Kh[5] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[3] - Kh[5] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[4] - Kh[5] + Kh[4])*r]], p[5], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5] - Ks[6] - Kh[5] + Kh[6])*r]]}, {v1*
       Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[0] - Kh[6] + Kh[0])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[1] - Kh[6] + Kh[1])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[2] - Kh[6] + Kh[2])*r]], 
      v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[3] - Kh[6] + Kh[3])*r]], 
      v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[4] - Kh[6] + Kh[4])*r]], 
      v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6] - Ks[5] - Kh[6] + Kh[5])*r]], p[6]}};
   S1 := Transpose[Eigenvectors[M1]] . 
     DiagonalMatrix[
      Exp[I*d*(Sqrt[(k*Cos[theta])^2 + Eigenvalues[M1]] - 
          k*Cos[theta])]] . Inverse[Transpose[Eigenvectors[M1]]];
   S2 := Transpose[Eigenvectors[M2]] . 
     DiagonalMatrix[
      Exp[I*d*(Sqrt[(k*Cos[theta])^2 + Eigenvalues[M2]] - 
          k*Cos[theta])]] . Inverse[Transpose[Eigenvectors[M2]]];
   S := S2 . S1;
   {{S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17}, {S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, 
      S26, S27}, {S31, S32, S33, S34, S35, S36, S37}, {S41, S42, S43, 
      S44, S45, S46, S47}, {S51, S52, S53, S54, S55, S56, S57}, {S61, 
      S62, S63, S64, S65, S66, S67}, {S71, S72, S73, S74, S75, S76, 
      S77}} = S;
   T = S11*Conjugate[S11] + S21*Conjugate[S21] + S31*Conjugate[S31] + 
     S41*Conjugate[S41] + S51*Conjugate[S51] + S61*Conjugate[S61] + 
     S71*Conjugate[
       S71] + (Conjugate[S11]*S21*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[1] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S51]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[4])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S51]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[4])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S61]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[5])*r]]) + 
     Conjugate[
      Conjugate[S11]*S21*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[1] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S11]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[0])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[2] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S21]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[1])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[3] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S31]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[2])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[4] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S41]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[3])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S51]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[5] - Kh[4])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S51]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[4])*r]] + 
       Conjugate[S61]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh[6] - Kh[5])*r]]];
   k^2*Sin[2*theta]*T];
G := NIntegrate[
   integrand[x, y, theta, fi], {x, x0 - 5*10^(-10), 
    x0 + 5*10^(-10)}, {y, y0 - 5*10^(-10), y0 + 5*10^(-10)}, {theta, 
    0, Pi/2}, {fi, 0, 2*Pi}];
G
```

Comment: Are the quantities `HBAR = 1.05457266*10^(-34);
ME = 9.1093897*10^(-31);` from the real world?

Comment: Yes, they are Plank constant and mass of one electron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(M2 = longExpression) evaluates (longExpression) only once, but (M2 := longExpression) evaluates (longExpression) each time (M2) is used. Evaluating (longExpression)  each time makes no difference, and it will be faster to use (M2 = longExpression). Likewise for S, S2.

This can be more efficient if you perform as much computation as possible that involves (HBAR, ME, ELEC, kc, ...). Getting this to run fast requires advanced programming. I will explain the techniques on this shorter version of your problem. You should look at the output (not shown here) from each step so you can understand what I am doing.

I find it hard to tell lower-case k from upper-case K, so I used K0 where you were using upper-case K.

Oddly, my first attempt to implement this using Compile gave a slightly different result for p[2] than if I didn't use Compile. I found that is because computing p[2] involved subtraction two numbers that are nearly identical. That can be prevented if I use Collect to perform some algebra on the expression that defines p[2]. However, I could only get that working if I do the algebra without having values assigned to (afa, K0, k) as I do here.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mu = 5;
HBAR = 1.05457266*10^(-34);
ME = 9.1093897*10^(-31);
ELEC = 1.60217733*10^(-19);
kc = Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2];
d = 0.335*10^(-9);
v1 = kc^2*3;
v2 = kc^2*2;
v3 = kc^2*1;
r = {x, y, 0};
Kh[0] = {0, 0, 0};
Kh[1] = {K0, 0, 0};
Ks[1] = {K0*Cos[afa], K0*Sin[afa], 0};
Kh[2] = {K0/2, K0*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[2] = {K0*Cos[afa + Pi/3], K0*Sin[afa + Pi/3], 0};
Kh[3] = {-K0/2, K0*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[3] = {K0*Cos[afa + 2*Pi/3], K0*Sin[afa + 2*Pi/3], 0};
Kh[4] = {-K0, 0, 0};
Ks[4] = {K0*Cos[afa + Pi], K0*Sin[afa + Pi], 0};
Kh[5] = {-K0/2, -K0*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[5] = {K0*Cos[afa + 4*Pi/3], K0*Sin[afa + 4*Pi/3], 0};
Kh[6] = {K0/2, -K0*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[6] = {K0*Cos[afa + 5*Pi/3], K0*Sin[afa + 5*Pi/3], 0};
ks = {k*sinTheta*cosFi, k*sinTheta*sinFi, k*cosTheta};
p[1] = Collect[k^2 - Total[(ks + Kh[1])^2], k];
p[2] = Collect[k^2 - Total[(ks + Kh[2])^2], k];
```

Notice I used (sinTheta, cosTheta, sinFi cosFi) in place of (Sin[theta], Cos[theta], Sin[fi], Cos[fi]). Once we have values for (theta, fi) the each Sin, Cos is only computed one time and assigned to symbols (sinTheta, cosTheta, sinFi cosFi). Computing the trig functions only once saves a lot of time. You might want to see what you get from evaluating p[1], p[2].

Next I define M1M2 where Block is used to ensure the computation is done with the appropriate values assigned to (afa, K0, k).

```
M1M2 = Block[{afa = Pi/90, K0 = 2.95*10^(10), k = kc*Sqrt[mu]},
M1 = {{v1, p[1]}, {p[2], v2}};
M2 = {
  {v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2]-Ks[1]-Kh[2]+Kh[1])*r]], p[2]},
  {p[1], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3] - Ks[4] - Kh[3] + Kh[4])*r]]}
};
{M1, M2}
```

];

You can evaluate {M1,M2}=M1M2 and see what is assigned to M1 and M2.
Now look how I can use With to insert the value of (expr) in an something that otherwise doesn't evaluate. I use With to do that sort of thing below.

expr = a + 2 a;
With[{expr = expr}, Hold[{2 + 6/3 + expr}]]
(* Hold {2, 6/3, 3 a} *)

M1M2compiled below will efficiently return {M1,M2}, but I need to ensure things are evaluated in the right order. Here (compile) doesn't evaluate it's arguments, and I use it as a place holder for (Compile). I need to ensure (Compile) doesn't do it's thing until I am ready.

```
SetAttributes[compile, {HoldAll}];
M1M2compiled = With[{M1M2 = M1M2},
  compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {theta, _Real}, {fi, _Real}}, 
  with[{cosFi = Cos[fi], cosTheta = Cos[theta], sinFi = Sin[fi], sinTheta = Sin[theta]}, 
  M1M2
], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"]]
```

Next I change (compile) to (Compile). I also change (with) to (With). With is used inside Compile to compute local constants {cosFi=Cos[fi],cosTheta=Cos[theta],sinFi=Sin[fi],sinTheta=Sin[theta]} as soon as we have numeric values for (theta,fi).

```
M1M2compiled = Apply[Compile, M1M2compiled /. with -> With];
```

Try this and see what you get for M1, M2.

```
{x, y, theta, fi} = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6};
{M1, M2} = M1M2compiled[x, y, theta, fi]
```

That might be enough to understand my the fastest version of the full blown computation below.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
mu = 5;
HBAR = 1.05457266*10^(-34);
ME = 9.1093897*10^(-31);
ELEC = 1.60217733*10^(-19);
kc = Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2];
d = 0.335*10^(-9);
v1 = kc^2*3;
v2 = kc^2*2;
v3 = kc^2*1;
r = {x, y, 0};
Kh[0] = {0, 0, 0};
Ks[0] = {0, 0, 0};
Kh[1] = {K0, 0, 0};
Ks[1] = {K0*Cos[afa], K0*Sin[afa], 0};
Kh[2] = {K0/2, K0*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[2] = {K0*Cos[afa + Pi/3], K0*Sin[afa + Pi/3], 0};
Kh[3] = {-K0/2, K0*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[3] = {K0*Cos[afa + 2*Pi/3], K0*Sin[afa + 2*Pi/3], 0};
Kh[4] = {-K0, 0, 0};
Ks[4] = {K0*Cos[afa + Pi], K0*Sin[afa + Pi], 0};
Kh[5] = {-K0/2, -K0*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[5] = {K0*Cos[afa + 4*Pi/3], K0*Sin[afa + 4*Pi/3], 0};
Kh[6] = {K0/2, -K0*Sqrt[3]/2, 0};
Ks[6] = {K0*Cos[afa + 5*Pi/3], K0*Sin[afa + 5*Pi/3], 0};
ks = {k*sinTheta*cosFi, k*sinTheta*sinFi, k*cosTheta};
Do[p[n] = Collect[k^2 - Total[(ks + Kh[n])^2], k], {n, 6}];
```

and

```
M1M2 = Block[{afa = Pi/90, K0 = 2.95*10^(10), k = kc*Sqrt[mu]},
M1 = {{0, v1, v1, v1, v1, v1, v1}, {v1, p[1], v1, v2, v3, v2, 
  v1}, {v1, v1, p[2], v1, v2, v3, v2}, {v1, v2, v1, p[3], v1, v2, 
  v3}, {v1, v3, v2, v1, p[4], v1, v2}, {v1, v2, v3, v2, v1, p[5], 
  v1}, {v1, v1, v2, v3, v2, v1, p[6]}};
M2 = {
  {0, v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0]-Ks[1]-Kh[0]+Kh[1])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0]-Ks[2]-Kh[0]+Kh[2])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0]-Ks[3]-Kh[0]+Kh[3])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0]-Ks[4]-Kh[0]+Kh[4])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0]-Ks[5]-Kh[0]+Kh[5])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[0]-Ks[6]-Kh[0]+Kh[6])*r]]},
  {v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1]-Ks[0]-Kh[1]+Kh[0])*r]],  p[1], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1]-Ks[2]-Kh[1]+Kh[2])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1]-Ks[3]-Kh[1]+Kh[3])*r]], v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1]-Ks[4]-Kh[1]+Kh[4])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1]-Ks[5]-Kh[1]+Kh[5])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[1]-Ks[6]-Kh[1]+Kh[6])*r]]},
  {v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2]-Ks[0]-Kh[2]+Kh[0])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2]-Ks[1]-Kh[2]+Kh[1])*r]], p[2], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2]-Ks[3]-Kh[2]+Kh[3])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2]-Ks[4]-Kh[2]+Kh[4])*r]], v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2]-Ks[5]-Kh[2]+Kh[5])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[2]-Ks[6]-Kh[2]+Kh[6])*r]]},
  {v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3]-Ks[0]-Kh[3]+Kh[0])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3]-Ks[1]-Kh[3]+Kh[1])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3]-Ks[2]-Kh[3]+Kh[2])*r]], p[3], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3]-Ks[4]-Kh[3]+Kh[4])*r]],  v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3]-Ks[5]-Kh[3]+Kh[5])*r]], v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[3]-Ks[6]-Kh[3]+Kh[6])*r]]},
  {v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4]-Ks[0]-Kh[4]+Kh[0])*r]], v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4]-Ks[1]-Kh[4]+Kh[1])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4]-Ks[2]-Kh[4]+Kh[2])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4]-Ks[3]-Kh[4]+Kh[3])*r]], p[4], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4]-Ks[5]-Kh[4]+Kh[5])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[4]-Ks[6]-Kh[4]+Kh[6])*r]]},
  {v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5]-Ks[0]-Kh[5]+Kh[0])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5]-Ks[1]-Kh[5]+Kh[1])*r]], v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5]-Ks[2]-Kh[5]+Kh[2])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5]-Ks[3]-Kh[5]+Kh[3])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5]-Ks[4]-Kh[5]+Kh[4])*r]], p[5], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[5]-Ks[6]-Kh[5]+Kh[6])*r]]},
  {v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6]-Ks[0]-Kh[6]+Kh[0])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6]-Ks[1]-Kh[6]+Kh[1])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6]-Ks[2]-Kh[6]+Kh[2])*r]], v3*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6]-Ks[3]-Kh[6]+Kh[3])*r]], v2*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6]-Ks[4]-Kh[6]+Kh[4])*r]], v1*Exp[I*Total[(Ks[6]-Ks[5]-Kh[6]+Kh[5])*r]], p[6]}
};
{M1, M2}
];
```

and

```
SetAttributes[compile, {HoldAll}];
M1M2compiled = With[{M1M2 = M1M2},
  compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {theta, _Real}, {fi, _Real}}, 
  with[{cosFi = Cos[fi], cosTheta = Cos[theta], sinFi = Sin[fi],sinTheta = Sin[theta]},
  M1M2],RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
(* Now we make M1M2compiled into a CompilefFunction. *)
M1M2compiled = Apply[Compile, M1M2compiled /. with -> With];
```

Next an efficint way to compute T.

```
afa = Pi/90;
K0 = 2.95*10^(10);
k = kc*Sqrt[mu];
Tcompiled = With[{Kh0 = Kh[0], Kh1 = Kh[1], Kh2 = Kh[2], Kh3 = Kh[3], 
Kh4 = Kh[4], Kh5 = Kh[5], Kh6 = Kh[6]}, 
Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {S11, _Complex}, {S12, _Complex}, \
{S13, _Complex}, {S14, _Complex}, {S15, _Complex}, {S16, _Complex}, \
{S17, _Complex}, {S21, _Complex}, {S22, _Complex}, {S23, _Complex}, \
{S24, _Complex}, {S25, _Complex}, {S26, _Complex}, {S27, _Complex}, \
{S31, _Complex}, {S32, _Complex}, {S33, _Complex}, {S34, _Complex}, \
{S35, _Complex}, {S36, _Complex}, {S37, _Complex}, {S41, _Complex}, \
{S42, _Complex}, {S43, _Complex}, {S44, _Complex}, {S45, _Complex}, \
{S46, _Complex}, {S47, _Complex}, {S51, _Complex}, {S52, _Complex}, \
{S53, _Complex}, {S54, _Complex}, {S55, _Complex}, {S56, _Complex}, \
{S57, _Complex}, {S61, _Complex}, {S62, _Complex}, {S63, _Complex}, \
{S64, _Complex}, {S65, _Complex}, {S66, _Complex}, {S67, _Complex}, \
{S71, _Complex}, {S72, _Complex}, {S73, _Complex}, {S74, _Complex}, \
{S75, _Complex}, {S76, _Complex}, {S77, _Complex}
 }, Module[{r = {x, y, 0}},
 S11*Conjugate[S11] + S21*Conjugate[S21] + S31*Conjugate[S31] + 
  S41*Conjugate[S41] + S51*Conjugate[S51] + S61*Conjugate[S61] + 
  S71*Conjugate[
    S71] + (Conjugate[S11]*S21*Exp[I*Total[(Kh1 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh2 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh3 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh4 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh2 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh3 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh4 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S31]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh3 - Kh2)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S31]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh4 - Kh2)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S31]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh2)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S31]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh2)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S41]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh4 - Kh3)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S41]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh3)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S41]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh3)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S51]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh4)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S51]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh4)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S61]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh5)*r]]) + 
  Conjugate[
   Conjugate[S11]*S21*Exp[I*Total[(Kh1 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh2 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh3 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh4 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S11]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh0)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S31*Exp[I*Total[(Kh2 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh3 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh4 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S21]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh1)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S31]*S41*Exp[I*Total[(Kh3 - Kh2)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S31]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh4 - Kh2)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S31]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh2)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S31]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh2)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S41]*S51*Exp[I*Total[(Kh4 - Kh3)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S41]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh3)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S41]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh3)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S51]*S61*Exp[I*Total[(Kh5 - Kh4)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S51]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh4)*r]] + 
    Conjugate[S61]*S71*Exp[I*Total[(Kh6 - Kh5)*r]]]],
RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
```

It' s sufficient to ensure one argument of integrand is NumericQ .

```
integrand[x_?NumericQ, y_, theta_, fi_] :=
Module[{M1, M2, S1, S2, S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17, S21, S22,
 S23, S24, S25, S26, S27, S31, S32, S33, S34, S35, S36, S37, S41, 
S42, S43, S44, S45, S46, S47, S51, S52, S53, S54, S55, S56, S57, 
S61, S62, S63, S64, S65, S66, S67, S71, S72, S73, S74, S75, S76, 
S77, T},
{M1, M2} = M1M2compiled[x, y, theta, fi];
S1 = Transpose[Eigenvectors[M1]] . 
 DiagonalMatrix[
  Exp[I*d*(Sqrt[(k*Cos[theta])^2 + Eigenvalues[M1]] - 
      k*Cos[theta])]] . Inverse[Transpose[Eigenvectors[M1]]]; 
S2 = Transpose[Eigenvectors[M2]] . 
 DiagonalMatrix[
  Exp[I*d*(Sqrt[(k*Cos[theta])^2 + Eigenvalues[M2]] - 
      k*Cos[theta])]] . Inverse[Transpose[Eigenvectors[M2]]];
{{S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17}, {S21, S22, S23, S24, S25, 
  S26, S27}, {S31, S32, S33, S34, S35, S36, S37}, {S41, S42, S43, 
  S44, S45, S46, S47}, {S51, S52, S53, S54, S55, S56, S57}, {S61, 
  S62, S63, S64, S65, S66, S67}, {S71, S72, S73, S74, S75, S76, 
  S77}} = S1 . S2;
T = Tcompiled[x, y, S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17, S21, S22, 
 S23, S24, S25, S26, S27, S31, S32, S33, S34, S35, S36, S37, S41, 
 S42, S43, S44, S45, S46, S47, S51, S52, S53, S54, S55, S56, S57, 
 S61, S62, S63, S64, S65, S66, S67, S71, S72, S73, S74, S75, S76, 
 S77];
Re[k^2*Sin[2*theta]*T]
];
```

finally

```
G=NIntegrate[integrand[x,y,theta,fi],{x,x0-5*10^(-10),x0+5*10^(-10)},
{y,y0-5*10^(-10),y0+5*10^(-10)},{theta,0,Pi/2},
{fi,0,2*Pi},AccuracyGoal->4,PrecisionGoal->3,MaxPoints->500000,
Method->"MonteCarlo"]
(* 721.714 *)
```

Comment: Dear Ersek, Thank you very much for your detailed answer. However, when I performed "Timing[G]", the above code give a result of {0., 723.402}, i.e., mathematica judge the time used is less than 1 second. But in fact, it need about 170 seconds to give the result, why? How many time do you need to get the result? (PS: there is a error "The integral failed to converge after 500100 integrand evaluations", and after performing the code, "sinTheta, cosFi, sinFi, cosTheta, compile, with" in the codes are blue.)

Comment: I am using Mathematica 12.2 with Mac-OS, and my computer computes G=721.923 in 245 seconds without error messages. (cosFi, cosTheta, sinFi, 
  sinTheta) should still be blue because they only had values 
assigned while computing M1M2compiled[__] for certain values of (x, y,
    theta, fi). Perhaps you are using a Mathematica version that has more strict criteria for convergence. You could avouid that message with a combination of (lowering PrecisionGoal, lowering AccuracyGoal, increasing MaxPoints).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your `integrand` takes big values, e.g.

```
integrand[0, 0, Pi/4, Pi/4]
```

> `3.54964*10^20 + 0. I`

and the cuboid is thin in two dimensions: its length in `x` and `y` equals `10^-9`. These circumstances make problems with the four-dimensional integration. Replacing the last lines of your code

```
G := NIntegrate[integrand[x, y, theta, fi], {x, x0 - 5*10^(-10), 
x0 + 5*10^(-10)}, {y, y0 - 5*10^(-10), y0 + 5*10^(-10)}, {theta, 
0, Pi/2}, {fi, 0, 2*Pi}];G
```

by

```
G := NIntegrate[integrand[x, y, theta, fi], {x, x0 - 5*10^(-10), 
x0 + 5*10^(-10)}, {y, y0 - 5*10^(-10), y0 + 5*10^(-10)}, {theta, 
0, Pi/2}, {fi, 0, 2*Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
Method -> "MonteCarlo"];G // Timing
```

, I obtain `{43.4219, 720.987}` without any warnings and errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.